# How to calculate ortho_scale of a viewport?

Tags: python, 3d-view, camera

There is an addon that allows you to save the current viewport to the camera.
But the addon only works in perspective mode.

For orthographic mode, you need to calculate the ortho_scale of the viewport and set the same for the camera.

More details in the latest messages at the link.
[Camera Fit View Add-on - Coding / Released Scripts and Themes - Blender Artists Community](https://blenderartists.org/t/camera-fit-view-add-on/1285195/26)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Please include all information here in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.